# pandas silent fail with pivot()

Tags: python, pandas

Probably very simple, but when trying to pivot a dataframe with pandas the line below is failing without throwing any exceptions.

```
pivoted_frame = raw_frame.pivot(index='timestamp', columns='signal_id', values='value')
```

raw_frame is a basic dataframe with 3 columns

```
         signal_id           timestamp      value
0               43 2019-03-05 13:40:00   2.341706
1               34 2019-03-05 13:40:00   4.459418
2               52 2019-03-05 13:40:00   2.076000
3               61 2019-03-05 13:40:00   3.500000
4               70 2019-03-05 13:40:00   0.930000
...            ...                 ...        ...
3688997         31 2020-03-05 13:30:00   2.290000
3688998         32 2020-03-05 13:30:00 -48.920000
3688999         33 2020-03-05 13:30:00 -48.920000
3689000         80 2020-03-05 13:30:00        NaN
3689001         81 2020-03-05 13:30:00        NaN
```

When executed with 12 months of data as in the above example `[3689002 rows x 3 columns]` then we complete with any issues, however if the volume of data is increased to 24 months `[7045105 rows x 3 columns]` then the line above fails, but throws no exceptions.

I would have expected a memory exception if that was the issue here?

Comment: Hmm, memory error are seldom tested by programmers, so almost anything can happen. A real world problem is that at the moment the error is detected, the error handler tries to format a message and asks some memory for that use... but the system has no more memory until the handler has completed its task! Long story short, if it fails because of memory exhausted, do not expect any nice behaviour...

Comment:  it was bugging out on that line due to memory earlier today. Ironic that it can’t report an out of memory exception because it’s “out of memory” itself.

Comment: I am not affirmative here. But I remember having to use static memory in C++ in error handlers to be immune to that problem. So I would not be surprised that it is the cause.

Comment: I’ve ended splitting the datasets by year and concatenating the resulting dataframes. Bit of a strange one as it’s not an excessively large dataset and the resource monitor isn’t showing high memory usage...